# Pycharm supress column on console using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried to print a dataframe to console on Pycharm, and got this:
[pycharm console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWOeU.png)

I used `print(dataframe)` only to print the dataframe.
How should I setup Pycharm to not do this?

Comment: I guess this an option in pandas itself

Answer (score 0):

This is an option of pandas itself.

```
ncols = 500 # Your number of cols to print

pd.set_option("display.max_columns", ncols)
```

You can do the same way with rows:

```
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", nrows)
```